# How to pattern match nested lists?

Tags: recursion, pattern-matching, smlnj, ml

In sml/nj, I want to create a function that takes a list of non-empty lists, and returns a list of the first elements of each of those non-empty lists.

```
fun get_first [] = []
 | get_first x::xs = (hd x)::get_first xs;
get_first: ('a list) list -> 'a list;
```

However this isn't working...
Does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to put parenthesis around your list pattern `x::xs`, like this:

```
fun get_first [] = []
  | get_first (x::xs) = (hd x)::get_first xs
```

The reason why it isn't working is a bit "complicated". In SML, lists are just defined as a datatype and some syntactic sugar. It basically looks something like this

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of ('a * 'a list)
```

As it is possible to pattern match upon datatype constructors, it is possible to pattern match against both `nil` (what you normally write as []) and `::`.
However, if you don't place parenthesis around it, then it will be interpreted as if the function was pattern matching 3 curried arguments. This is perhaps better visualised like this

```
  | get_first (x) (::) (xs) = ....
```

Also do note that you could easily implement this, using the map function

```
fun get_first xs = map hd xs
```

Comment: To be pedantic, since ``::`` is given infix status in the standard lib, the 2nd clause of the original code is actually parsed as ``(get_first x)::xs = ...``, which in turn is sugar for ``op:: (get_first x, xs) = ...``. In other words, it's trying to define a function named ``::``.

Comment: @Andreas: That would be true if it was in the function body, however since it is part of a function clause it gets parsed differently, as seen by one of the error messages: get_first = (fn nil => nil | (x,_,xs) => hd <exp> :: get_first <exp>). Here it is seen that the second clause gets parsed into the pattern that matches a tripple. Thus it gets parsed as 3 curried arguments in the first place.

Comment: Shrug. Strictly speaking it is simply a syntax error, because an infix function clause does only allow atomic patterns as arguments (for whatever reason). I don't know why SML/NJ (which I suppose is what you tried) does even attempt to type-check it at that point. Either way, I don't see how its interpretation makes any sense.